# Is there any native C-level lock other than os_unfair_lock in Objective-C/Swift?

Tags: ios, c, macos, synchronization

I got curious and started looking for all available C-level synchronization tools in iOS/macOS platform. However, based on the official documents (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/synchronization?language=objc), `os_unfair_lock` seems to be the only available synchronization tools out there.

Am I missing anything? Where are all the C-level semaphore/monitor tools?

Comment: Pretty sure you can `#include <semaphore.h>` and use `sem_wait`, etc.

Comment: The argument to @synchronized()is used to identify the lock. It can be any Objective-C object; self is a convenient choice here. If several different blocks of code are synchronized using the same argument to @synchronized(), the blocks are all locked with the same lock. Once a thread acquires the lock and enters one of those blocks, other threads are prevented from entering any of those blocks until the first thread gives up the lock by exiting the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the old C locks are there, but they’re trying to steer everyone towards `os_unfair_lock`, nowadays. See the [Concurrent Programming with GCD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=997) where they discuss C lock mechanisms (and how you’d use them in Swift if you wanted to), and this discussion touches upon their thought process regarding locks nowadays.

But you can use [`pthread_mutex_t`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3.html) like before. Or if you’re dealing with an atomic, you can use [`OSAtomicXXX`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/OSAtomicAdd32.3.html). The old spinlock has been deprecated, with this `os_unfair_lock` recommended in lieu of that. All of these options are buried in the [`man` pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/index.html).

Needless to say, from Objective-C, you still have [`NSLock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslock?language=objc), [`NSRecursiveLock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrecursivelock?language=objc) and the `@synchronized` directive, too.

The old [Threading Programming Guide: Using Locks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW16) enumerates a few of the locking alternatives.